# How to get the default value set by the xml schema?

Tags: python, lxml

I've got an xml schema which specifies a default value for an optional field...

```
<xs:element name="expiry" type="xs:positiveInteger" default="86400"/>
```

I'm using [lxml](http://lxml.de) to parse the incoming xml...

```
root = lxml.etree.XML(xml)
```

When I go looking for the optional element, and it's not there, I get a 'None' result...

```
expiry = root.findtext('expiry')
```

How would I get the expiry value to default to the schema's default (86400)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be done by 'magic'. The long way is the only way (today).

That is: read the xmlschema like an xml document, find the element tag with the attribute "expiry", look for the value of the attribute "default" in that tag.

Comment: What is the best way to find the XSD element, that corresponds to the XML node?

Comment: @GillBates In the schema document, find the xs:element which has a name attribute matching your xml node.

Comment: you can get multiple results like that - how to determine which one is correct?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to include you schema, using lxml.etree.XMLSchema

I think it only does validation, but you may want to try to parse your XML together with the schema and see if the "default" value appears.